Using the keys of an object literal as a Typescript type even if the object literal is also typed?
I want to use the keys of an object as a type somewhere else and found a solution here: Using the keys of an object literal as a Typescript type?
However, in my case I would also like to have a type restriction for the original object literal so that when working on it I have Typescript support.
But doing so leads to the type inference not working as in the linked solution anymore.
As an example:
I would like to be able to use the keys of data as shown here:
const data = Object.freeze({
    some: "abc",
    long: {"a":"b"},
    list: ["c"],
    of: "",
    things: "b",
});

type data_key = keyof typeof data;

// leads to:
// type data_key = "some" | "long" | "list" | "of" | "arbitrary" | "things"

But when I add a type to data, this is not possible anymore:
const data: { [key: string]: string | object } = Object.freeze({
    some: "abc",
    long: {"a":"b"},
    list: ["c"],
    of: "",
    things: "b",
});

type data_key = keyof typeof data;

// leads to:
// type data_key = string | number

The type inference from the first example seems to be overridden somehow. Is there any way to combine the two example in order to provide a type to the object literal and later infer a new type from the keys of that object literal?
Edit with an updated example
The reason I want to have this is that data is a somewhat complex JSON structure that I want to be able to edit and have typescript support while editing to avoid mistakes. But then I need the keys defined there also at other places, but want them to be defined only there as a kind of single source of truth.
So it would be more like this:
type Fruit = {
    "color": string,
    "taste": string
}

const data: {[key: string]: Fruit} = Object.freeze({
    apple: {
             "color": "red",
             "taste": "sweet"
           },
    banana: {
             "color": "yellow",
             "taste": "sweet"
           },
    peach: {
             "color": "orange",
             "taste": "sweet"
           },
    grape: {
             "color": "violet",
             "taste": "sweet"
           }
});

type data_key = keyof typeof data;

// leads to:
// type data_key = string | number
// But I would like to have:
// type data_key = "apple" | "banana" | "peach" | "grape"

And when adding new fruits to data I want typescript support to add all the fields of an object, but I later also want to refer to all the fruits defined in data
If this is not compatible with the way typescript is defined, then I guess I need to live with it or remove the type information from data..

Annotating the type of data explicitly throws away the information you care about. I'd suggest doing this in two steps: keep the inferred type of the object literal (renamed out of the way) and then use that to define both your type and your const, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Then all you want is the satisfies operator as shown in this playground link. This is likely a duplicate so I'll close it as one soon

@jcalz thank you for the explanation and the suggestion. I edited the original post to make my motivation more clear. This would to some extent help, but as written, I would like to have typescript support while editing data. Your linked example would provide a syntax error if some type in data is wrong, but it would not be directly highlighted in data, but the afterwards defined object

@jcalz yes, the satisfies keyword solves my problem, thank you!

The reason this happens is because in your second example you are explicitly setting the type of the keys of your data object to be of type string instead of "some" | "long" | "list" | "of" | "arbitrary" | "things". This is correct Typescript behavior.
A possible approach, although I'm not sure why this would be useful, would be:
enum PossiblKeys {
  some = 'some',
  long = 'long',
  list = 'list',
  of = 'of',
  things = 'things',
}

const data: Record<PossiblKeys, string | object> = {
  some: "abc",
  long: {"a":"b"},
  list: ["c"],
  of: "",
  things: "b",
};

type data_key = `${keyof typeof data}`;

First you have to define an enum with the keys you will use for the data object, and then you can use the syntax in the last line to retrieve all the keys from the object and convert them to a union type. Note that it would be the same as doing ${PossibleKeys}, but I'm assuming you have a specific need to build data_key from data specifically.

thanks for your answer! However, I do not want to specify the keys twice. That's why the suggested satisfies keyword is a better solution for me
